# Does quaternion data become inaccurate when the gyroscope spins at a rate faster than the maximum rotation it can measure?

Tags: sensor

I am currently using an invensense MPU9250 sensor board. The gyroscope measures a maximum of 2000dps. I record the quaternion value at an initial position which is <1,0,0,0> and then I rotate the board really fast. When the board returns to this initial position, the quaternion is not the same.
Is it because the spin rate was more than the gyro could measure?

Comment: Please tell us if you ask the question twice: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39133/does-quaternion-data-become-inaccurate-when-the-gyroscope-spins-at-a-rate-faster

Answer (score 0):

Rotational position is the 2nd integral of acceleration and cumulative position errors increase with g levels.

That's why there is a 3D magnetometer and calibration procedure.

Comment: I have calibrated the magnetometer and calibrated the sensor but after the gyro value starts recording maximum values the quaternions do not match the initial one. However for spin rates lesser than 2000dps, the quaternions are stable.

Comment: Then examine card for CM noise induced errors

Comment: If you have a CM choke for power, you might be able to get better results. Then use a CM choke for output data to host avoid ground shift CM noise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the difference in the quaternion values were large, you are probably right.

The three gyroscopes packaged in the MPU9250 sensor board measure the three components of the angular velocity of the board.  These three angular rates are converted to four quaternions rates.

Given initial conditions for the quaternions (which is probably determined from the accelerometers and magnetometers when at rest), the quaternion rates are integrated from their initial values to obtain the instantaneous values of the quaternions while in operation.

If the board is rotated too fast, one or more of the gyroscopes will saturate (giving out a lower value than the actual rate), resulting in the quaternion rates to also saturate, leading to wrong answers in the calculated quaternion values.

If the differences in the quaternion values were small, it could simply have been the errors in the gyro measurements (such as drift), which were integrated to result in quaternions errors.